# How to render PixiJs on top of another canvas, while keeping it interactive?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I'm trying to render PixiJs on top of the content produced by another canvas. I have basically the same problem as in this question: [Use an existing canvas without losing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66955027/use-an-existing-canvas-without-losing-contents-in-pixi-js)

One answer suggests to use 3 canvases with 2 being off-screen and the third one combines the result of the two. It works but I lose any interaction events I get from the Pixi Canvas, and thus can't implement things like drag / pin / zoom. I may also need to be able to listen to events from the first non-pixi canvas too. How do I work around this problem? Can put the 3 canvases on top of each other as html elements and somehow catch all the events?

Comment: Can't you place the two canvas elements on top of each other? (using `position:absolute`). One runs your original canvas app, and the pixi canvas is placed on top. The pixi canvas can be transparent, so you will still see the underlying canvas.

Comment: @Kokodoko Yes I've taken that approach of 2 canvases you mentioned (I stack it with a 1x1 grid though). For the interaction I just forward the pixi events to the background canvas using eventDispatch.